# Diophantine equation: $y^2=1+12x+16x^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving

The diophantine equation $$y^2=1+12x+16x^2$$ only has solutions $x=0, y=\pm1$ according to wolfram alpha. How would I go about proving these are the only solutions?

Similarly the equation $$y^2=5+12x+16x^2$$ has solutions $x=-1, y=\pm3$.

Is there a general method with regards to these types of equations? Thanks.

Comment: The technique I know is to try to reduce each side mod different numbers, and show that it leads to contradictions

Comment: $$y^2=16x^2+12x+5$$  This is the same as.  $$(2y-8x-3)(2y+8x+3)=11$$

Comment: $$y^2=16x^2+12x+1$$ This is the same as. $$(8x+3-2y)(8x+3+2y)=5$$

Comment: Thanks. Very nice. Is there a name for this technique and conditions when it works and when it doesn't? I need to look this up and study it. ie: what happens when the coefficient of x^2 is not a perfect square etc....

Comment: In this case, solutions are defined by the equations Pell.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+12x+16x^2$ is closest to $(4x+1)^2$ and $(4x+2)^2$ regardless of $x\geq0$ or $x<0$, as it is easy to see the distance from $(4x)^2$ and $(4x+3)^2$ to $1+12x+16x^2$ are strictly larger. You need to check both equality and finds out it has integer solution only when $x=0$

Similarly,

$5+12x+16x^2$ is closest to $(4x+1)^2$ and $(4x+2)^2$ as well, the equality holds only when $5+12x+16x^2=(4x+1)^2$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: What about all the other 4x+a's? For every a, (4x+a)^2 is at 0 distance from 1+12+16x^2, for some x. It's just that these x values are not integers.

Comment: To show this clearly, we need to break into two cases for non-negative and negative and for the non-negative case, we can see that $1+8x+16x^2\leq1+12x+16x^2<4+16x+16x^2$, for the negative case we can also see $1+8x+16x^2>1+12x+16x^2\geq4+16x+16x^2$. My answer combines this two cases in one sentence, the point is that you need to check both sides.

Comment: In addition, the equation (or the inequalities themselves) are based on the assumption that $x$ is integer, when you solve them either it has a solution or it does no have a solution. Non-integer solutions are not allowed.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you. But I don't understand how you know integer values are not possible at higher (4x+a)'s. For example for $(4x+100)^2$, it's at a distance 0 from $1+12x+16x^2$ when $x = -9999/788$. The distance from (4x+1) and (4x+2) is nonzero at this x value. So it's closer to $(4x+100)^2$ at this x value. It's not an integer value, but there might be a higher a that hits zero distance at an integer x value.

Comment: Well, the whole point is that, we are trying to find two "square numbers" that bounds $1+12x+16x^2$ inside, we know it is in between $(4x+1)^2$ and $(4x+2)^2$ so for it to be an integer, it must equal to one of them. For your example when $x=-{9999\over788}$, you are ignoring the fact that $(4x+a)^2$ are square numbers for all $a$, for example, if you substitute your $x$ into your $(4x+100)^2$, you won't even get an integer.

Comment: And well, if you mean $y$ does not have to be an integer and $y^2$ does not have to be a square number, then sure there are infinite number of solutions.

Comment: I understand now. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No problem. The primary misunderstanding comes from you are trying to find a solution first and then restricting it to integer while my solution first restrict $x$ and $y$ to integers and then tries to find a solution.